# Some questions appear greyed out

Tags: support, questions

Today some questions appear like those in the red rectangles in the picture. It's the first time this has happened.

> [image: screenshot]

It's a bug?

Comment: Do you have `javascript` as an ignored tag?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Only accidentally does do that... Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This faded formatting indicates that the question is tagged with one of your ignored tags. Based on your image, I'd guess that ignored tag is [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

You can change your ignored tags by selecting the `Edit` link next to "Favorite Tags" on the right hand bar (under the community bulletin)

[image: Ignored Tags]

From here you can add or remove tags you wish to ignore.

Comment: If they're ignored, why do they show up at all and waste space on the screen?

Comment: I cannot remember asking CSS to be ignored. This kicked in today

Comment: @ekolis You (now) get the option of whether to hide or gray such tags.

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh really? That's cool! How do I do that? I don't see the option on the tags page, and I can't seem to find a profile settings page either...

Comment: @ekolis I see this option when I hit "Add an ignored tag" on the desktop interface. There's a box for the tag to add, and two radio buttons for hide&gray